# Error finding google services classpath in Android

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

On adding `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'` to build.gradle i am getting this error. Any solution for this?

```
    Error:Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.3.1/google-services-3.3.1.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.3.1/google-services-3.3.1.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/3.3.1/google-services-3.3.1.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/3.3.1/google-services-3.3.1.jar
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/3.3.1/google-services-3.3.1.pom
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/3.3.1/google-services-3.3.1.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1' // google-services plugin
    }
}

def isReleaseBuild() {
    return version.contains("SNAPSHOT") == false
}

allprojects {
    version = VERSION_NAME
    group = GROUP

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-reporting'
```

Comment: Have you tried `Sync Project with Gradle Files`?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things.

PROJECT LEVEL BUILD.GRADLE

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.31"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1' 
}
```

I'd suggest lowering your version to 3.2.1 as there are known issues in 3.3.1 affecting compiling around modules, flavors and more.

Secondly please show that you applied the plugin properly in your module build.gradle as well.

EXAMPLE BELOW:

MODULE LEVEL BUILD.GRADLE

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.2"

    //to compile @synchronized things and java references
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.31"

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.wajahatkarim3.EasyFlipView:EasyFlipView:2.0.5'

    // [START firebase]
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
    // [END   firebase]

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }  

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Of course you only care about the google gms parts, so make sure you have that plugin and dependency in place.